# How to get a dom element in a new window?

Tags: javascript, window

A simple task in JavaScript is to open a new window and writing inside. But I need to write in a dom element, a div with an ID.

```
var novoForm = window.open("somform.html", "wFormx", "width=800,height=600,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,titilebar=no,resizable=no,");
```

Than I try something...

```
var w = novoForm.innerWidth;
var h = novoForm.innerHeight;
novoForm.document.getElementById("monitor").innerHTML = 'Janela: '+w+' x '+h;
```

I did it to see if the object "novoForm" is valid. But nothing is written in "monitor" div. I also try using onload event with no success. I'm wondering if it's some security restriction or am I missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, this is a solution:

```
var novoForm = window.open("somform.html", "wFormx", "width=800,height=600,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,titilebar=no,resizable=no,");
var teste = function(){
    var mon = novoForm.document.getElementById("monitor");
    if(typeof(mon)!="undefined"){
        //novoForm.alert("Achei!");
        var h = novoForm.innerHeight;
        var strh = String(h - 40 - 30)+'px';
        novoForm.document.getElementById("pagina").style.height = strh;
        novoForm.document.getElementById("monitor").innerHTML = '<p class="legenda">&copy; NetArts | gustavopi</p>';
        clearInterval(id);
    }
}
var id = setInterval(teste, 100);
```

This will do the job. Not a "pretty" solution to me, but it works!

Answer (score 11):

You've done it right, but you *do* need to be sure to use `onload` (or poll), because it takes a moment for the page to get loaded in the new window.

Here's a full working example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/iyeqer/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iyeqer/1/edit)

```
(function() {

  document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = function() {

    var novoForm = window.open("http://jsbin.com/ugucot/1", "wFormx", "width=800,height=600,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,titilebar=no,resizable=no,");
    novoForm.onload = function() {
      var w = novoForm.innerWidth;
      var h = novoForm.innerHeight;
      novoForm.document.getElementById("monitor").innerHTML = 'Janela: '+w+' x '+h;
    };
  };
})();
```

> I'm wondering if it's some security restriction or am I missing something...

Not in your example as shown, no, because the page is clearly being loaded from the same origin. If the URL were from a *different* origin, then yes, you'd be running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which prohibits cross-origin scripting. You can relax that via the `document.domain` property, having both the window containing the code above and the window being loaded setting `document.domain` to the same value. From [the link above](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#document.domain_property):

> If two windows (or frames) contain scripts that set domain to the same value, the same-origin policy is relaxed for these two windows, and each window can interact with the other. For example, cooperating scripts in documents loaded from orders.example.com and catalog.example.com might set their document.domain properties to “example.com”, thereby making the documents appear to have the same origin and enabling each document to read properties of the other.

More about `document.domain` can be found [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.domain). Note that it only works where both documents share a common parent domain, e.g., so it works for `app1.example.com` and `app2.example.com` if they both set to `example.com`, but not for `example1.com` and `example2.com` because they have not common value they can set.

Comment: I try with onload, but this evenet isn't firing. Not sure why, I'll do more tests...

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think the `document.domain` thing only works when the parent domain name is the same for both windows. For example, a Google parent and Stackoverflow popup can't use this to communicate. Not sure though

Comment: @Ian: Sorry, yes, I should have flagged that up. (And yes, that's correct.) Done.

Comment: I mean, I would hope that was obvious, but I guess it's important to know :)

Comment: Still couldn't make the onload fire. It seams the window opens before the event to be implemented. There is no "new Window()" constructor so I don't know how to create a window object and do it right. Maybe in the real web it will work, but is not reliable. So I did a testing function and a setInterval to discover when the "monitor" div will be available for me. It's not a pretty solution, but it works.

Comment: @GustavoPinent: Functional is all the pretty you really need. :-) Congrats on it. I haven't tried it with the target page definitely served from cache, that's probably what's happening, there's definitely a race condition there. I'd probably use `onload`, but back it up with a timer.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what url you try to load into the new window. @T.J is right on that. Also note that if you just want to load a blank document you can load "about:blank" into the url.  The only difference is that you would use outerWidth since you haven't loaded an actual document.

```
var novoForm = window.open("about:blank", "wFormx", "width=800,height=600,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,titilebar=no,resizable=no,");
var w = novoForm.outerWidth;
var h = novoForm.outerHeight;
novoForm.document.body.innerHTML = 'Janela: '+w+' x '+h;
```