# Unable to access parent popup div element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been working on this little script where the translated text is supposed to return in its original position. Everything seems fine, but the js is still unable to find the window object. Is there anything wrong in code? I have tried newXWin.document too, but no use. Please assist.

```html
<?php

?>

<html>

<head>
<script>
function DoMagic()
{
var newWin = window.open("https://translate.google.com/#auto/es/This%20is%20a%20test%20sentence.%0AI%20think%20I%20should%20try%20this.","newXWin","width=500,height=600");
}

function GetText()
{
alert(window.opener.document.getElementById("result_box").innerHTML + "");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='toDiv'></div>
<a href='#' onclick='javascript:DoMagic();'>Get Page</a>

<a href='#' onclick='javascript:GetText();'>Get Contents!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see `result_box` defined anywhere.

Comment: Maybe it better to make var newWin as global, and use it in function getText(). I see no use of newWin any more exempt doMagic(),it's strange...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a dom element in a new window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880468/how-to-get-a-dom-element-in-a-new-window)