# Get an element by class and make it open in a new tab

Tags: javascript, css, class, new-window

I got some links in my HTML built by a WordPress shortcode. Unfortunately this shortcode do not include the target property and this way I cannot make the links open in a new tab.

I am not a programmer and I'm looking for a little JS to make some links under a specific class open in a new tab.

Something like:

```
if ("a" tag is under "div.newTab" class) onClick {window.open in a new tab}
```

Hope you guys understand it!

Thank you all.

Comment: [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880468/how-to-get-a-dom-element-in-a-new-window)

Comment: Do you need the class to be evaluated at the time of the click, or can the the link be flagged to open in a new window based on whether it has the class on load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var allLinks = document.querySelectorAll("div.newTab a");
    for(var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++){
        var currentLink = allLinks[i];
        currentLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `target` attribute by looping through all the links under a specified class.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/xdmof62b/1/)

```js
(function(){

 $(".newTab a").each(function(i, obj){
  
   obj.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
 
  });
 
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="newTab">
  <a href="https://bhansa.github.io">bhansa</a>
  <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to avoid manipulating a lot of links on the page, you could use jQuery to catch clicks on links in .newTab divs and act on them.

Example HTML

```
<div class="someClass">
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</div>

<div class="newTab">
    <a href="http://wikipedia.org">Wikipedia</a>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( '.newTab a' ).click( function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open(( this ).href, '_blank');
    });
});
```

Working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sauntimo/y9t82t22/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.newTab a', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
    window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.