# How to get parent object ID when clicking on ellipse element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, parent-child

If I'm interpreting correct hierarchy of elements, **what I'm wanting to do would be** ...

That element `<ellipse>` children of `<svg>`, `<object>` and  `<div id="svg_*">` when clicked showed me the id of your `<object>` parent.

*this * is because the `<ellipse>` will be from your respective svg div.*

This is how my HTML strtucture is, thoses #DOCUMENT are window.frames opened by each `<object>` tag.

```html
<body>

  <div id="content">

    <div class="header"></div>
    <nav class="nav"></nav>

    <div class="div 1"></div>

    <div class="div 2">
      
      <div id="svg_1">
        <object id="OneNameObject" data="../folder/fileOne.svg">
           #DOCUMENT
              <svg>
                <ellipse>I have one addEventerLinster Click here</ellipse>
             
             </svg>
        </object>
      </div>

      <div id="svg_2">
        <object id="TwoNameObject" data="../folder/fileTwo.svg">
           #DOCUMENT
              <svg>
                <ellipse>I have one addEventerLinster Click here</ellipse>
             
             </svg>
        </object>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="div 3"></div>
    <div class="div 4"></div>

    </div>
```

For now I'm getting access to the `<object> id` when I specify the index of it to be used.

> 0 for svg_1 #document
>
> 1 for svg_2 #document

So I thought I'd use the **this** selector to call the ellipse hireararchy. But I could not, and i don't know how.

something like :

```
this.parent.document.querySelector('object').id;
```

This is the way i getting the `id` using index, and by this - for sure - i aways get the id from selected `<object>`.

```js
window.onload = function (){  
    
  //This is for addEventLinster on each <ellipse>.
  var obj = document.querySelectorAll('object');    
  
   for (var x = 0; x < obj.length; x++){              
    
    var svg = obj[x].contentDocument.querySelector('svg');
    var e = svg.querySelectorAll('ellipse');
  
       for ( var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
    
            e[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    
            var objId = parent.document.getElementsByTagName('object')[0].id;
                  
            alert(  objId  );  
               
            }); 
       }
   }
};
```

**Working Example** \ but not functional on my context.

> This code is working, but it's not on my context ! Need to get that info, I am using `<object>` data attr to load svg files, they come on embed tags with a new window frame and a new document page. That is why i cant get they elements so easy.

[Image HTML Code / DOM painel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73gT5.png)  - * detail :  ellipses is on `<g>` tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

         var obj = $('ellipse');      
         
         obj.on('click', function(){
         
         alert($(this).parents('object').attr('id'));
         
         });
                 
});
```

```css
div {

width: 52px;
margin: 2px;
border-radius: 10%;
}

#svg_1:hover, #svg_2:hover {

opacity: 0.7;

}


#svg_1 {

border: 2px solid indianred;

}

#svg_2 {

border: 2px solid lightblue;

}
```

```html
<html>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="content">

    <div class="header"></div>
    <nav class="nav"></nav>

    <div class="div 1"></div>

    <div class="div 2">
      
      <div id="svg_1">
        <object id="redObject" data="">
           <!-- #DOCUMENT -->
 
 <svg width="50" height="48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  
  <ellipse ry="14" rx="13" id="svg_2" cy="25" cx="25" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#cd5c5c" fill="#bf2a2a"/>

</svg>

        </object>
      </div>
            <div id="svg_2">
        <object id="blueObject" data="">
          
          <!-- #DOCUMENT -->
 <svg width="50" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  
  <ellipse ry="14" rx="13" id="svg_2" cy="25" cx="25" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#c95c5c" fill="#56aaff"/>

</svg>

        </object>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="div 3"></div>
    <div class="div 4"></div>

    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

ps; I found the title of the question a bit confusing, in case someone has a better suggestion, I would appreciate it!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get? The ID of the object which contains the clicked item?

Comment: No, i want get the ID from Object. Ellipse will be the "button" to parent reference.

Comment: Well there are some syntax errors in your js, your closing brackets/braces are messed up. Can you provide a simplified working example?

Comment: will using Jquery be fine for you?

Comment: @G_S of course, i dont mind (:

Comment: @Huangism hmm i'll provide it as soon i can.

Comment: Check below answer if thats working for you.

Comment: @Huangism i add some working example just to show what i want. But it is not what i need, i really dont know how to use the data attr here on stackoverflow examples. So ,need to know there is new document window opened for each `<object>` on page. Thanks for the title!

Comment: So your object tags is actually loaded in a new window?

Comment: So you want the nearest "object" ancestor? Or you want the element that the svg's "document" lives inside? (I understand you want the "id" value, but what do you want the id value of?)

Comment: @Huangism Yes! :)

Comment: @Anthony `<object>` ancestor id.

Comment: @Yemoja ok then you need to show how you are opening the windows. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880468/how-to-get-a-dom-element-in-a-new-window if this solves your problem then I can mark this as a duplicate

Comment: @Huangism added code picture on question. I still studying the link you gave.

Comment: @Yemoja I don't know how that picture is related to the question. We need to see the code that creates the new window

Comment: @Huangism there's no code creating new window. Am not using anything like " window.open ". It's about the embedded content. Maybe i forget to tell about the type of `<object>` it's image/xml+svg. And about it  - " The resource referenced by the ‘image’ element represents a separate document which generates its own parse tree and document object model (if the resource is XML). "  - [w3.org About Embedded Content](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/embedded.html)

Comment: @Yemoja are you saying there is an iframe or something inside of the object? Can you put the generated code of the object tag? as in what's #document stand for?

Answer (score 0):

Give the below a try. (Not a tested code but should ideally work unless some syntax issues or so)
We can check if something can unnecessary can be removed.

```
$.each($('[id^="svg_"]'),function(){
    var eclipse = $(this).find("object").find('svg').find('ellipse'); 
     console.log(eclipse) 
   $(eclipse).click(function (){
     alert($(this).parent().parent().attr('id'))
   })
});
```

Comment: What's the point of using `$.each`? You can just bind the click to the ellipse and instead of `parent()` just do `closest('object')`

Comment: yeah.. let me see if i can do a snippet for that

Comment: but from the question it says, eclipse should be child of svg , object and div_ and thats the reason I gave a try with $.each to get divs first and the appropriate objects

Comment: Yes I think so, based on the given code, you can just do `$('#content').find('ellipse').on( 'click', function() { ... } )`

Comment: The `ellipse` are the child of svg, object and div, but there is no point going through them using each when you can directly grab them and get to their parent object. That's just the html structure it does not mean you have to get the element in that order with js

Comment: @G_G I'll check this carefully and come back to say about!

Comment: @G_S Even so I can not still access the elements because they are in separate documents. If it was a single document, it would work fine the code, and worth the simplifications mentioned by Huangism, but my biggest problem is being accessing the #document children. I put some information and images of the actual structure of the code, if you can take a look ... (: