# Can't get elements of child window after window.open()

Tags: javascript, document, html2canvas, window.open

I opened a child window by using window.open() in jquery.

```
var child = window.open("http://localhost/example.html");
  console.log(child);
  console.log(child.document);
```

when I check the console logs, it returns empty **DOM-elements**

I almost tried everything but nothing changes.

check the img pls haha

[Console log Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz3PI.png)

So the goal is to open an html file in new window as child and save it as image file by Html2canvas!

**All I need is to get child window's elements!**

Things I tried :

```
child.document.getElementById("myDiv")
```

Comment: Is the window you opened within the same [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) as the page that opens it? You can't access the DOM of other websites for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, it's the same origin! That code above is to show the example.
I opened a new window from http://localhost
And the opened new window is like http://localhost/test.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a dom element in a new window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880468/how-to-get-a-dom-element-in-a-new-window)

Comment: It works! Thanks!!!!!!!!!!! I used Interval and worked! thanks again!